# background color, background image did not fill in the whole css box model

Tags: css, background, background-color

I have this problem than could not figure out why. The background color, background image did not fill in the whole css box model no matter what I adjust it.

http://imageoneads.com/kmplumbing/plumbing.htm

Could it be some css specific rule overlapped somewhere in my codes?

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks
David

Comment: Seems OK to me.
Whats the problem with your background, Let we know more details about that, could be a Browser css issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `background-color: #F9F0D3;` from `plumbingText2`.

If you are tying to hide the background use:

```
#plumbingText2 {
    background-color: #F9F0D3;
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and add `valign="top"` to your `<td>`:

```
<td valign="top" height="" colspan="2" rowspan="3">  <div id="plumbingText2">
```

Another option is to leave out the `valign` tag and use:

```
#plumbingText2 {
background-color: #F9F0D3;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

and set the `style` on the `<ul>`:

```
<ul style="border: medium none; margin: 0;">
```

Comment: Wow, set the < border: medium none: > has fixed it. Thanks so much Dave. What exactly does it mean, thou?

Comment: I think you fixed it by changing more than just the border, but im glad it helped. border: none; means you dont want any border around you element, the medium part came out of firebug which I used to look at your html, if you haven't used firebug take a look at it, it will make solving these issues alot easier.

Comment: @David:  Don't forget to "accept" this answer since it solved your problem.